# How do I get the UserId at login using asp.net Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-identity, identity

I want to get the UserId of the user successfully logging in so I can write it to a database with a timestamp for auditing purposes. This is the code fragment from the Login cs file

```
if (Page.IsValid)
{
// Validate the user password
var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
var signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();

var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn((this.LoginView1.FindControl("username") as TextBox).Text, (this.LoginView1.FindControl("password") as TextBox).Text, (this.LoginView1.FindControl("RememberMe") as CheckBox).Checked, shouldLockout: false);

switch (result)
{
case SignInStatus.Success:
IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
break;
```

I tried adding

```
string thisuser = User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString();
```

and also

```
string thisuser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString;
```

before the redirect, but in each case it returns a null value. Where can I actually get the userid from if not in this Login method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always find your user by name. Since the login was successful, there is no problem usint the UserName.

```
var userName = ((this.LoginView1.FindControl("username") as TextBox).Text;

//...

switch (result)
{
    case SignInStatus.Success:
        var loggedInUser = manager.FindByName(userName);

        //Do your log with loggedInUser!

        IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
        break;
    //...
}
```